# Error locating assembly descriptor: assembly/webapp.xml Netbeans

Tags: java, xml, frameworks, zk

i'm starting to learn about zk framework and i am reading the theory behind this interesting framework and trying to understand its way of working.

From here:

https://github.com/zkoss/zkessentials/tree/zk8

I downloaded the .zip file, open it with netbeans, import the necessary libraries, run it on apache, well so far it starts to run but it fails and the full error is this one:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-    plugin:2.2:single (webapp) on project essentials: Error reading assemblies: Error locating assembly descriptor: assembly/webapp.xml
>
> [1] [INFO] Searching for file location: C:\Users\user\Documents\Demos ZK\zkessentials-zk8-spring\assembly\webapp.xml
>
> [2] [INFO] File: C:\Users\User\Documents\Demos ZK\zkessentials-zk8-spring\assembly\webapp.xml does not exist.
>
> [3] [INFO] File: C:\Users\Algo\User\Demos ZK\zkessentials-zk8-spring\assembly\webapp.xml does not exist.
>   -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I searched in many sites but i cannot solve it. I hope you can help me with my problem, thanks for your time.

Comment: looks like apache is searching on a bad location.  I suggest try to run in jetty first, it's lighter and faster.

Comment: Ok, i will try that and tell you later the results, thank you very much.

Comment: It worked, sorry for answer so late.